# Software for record retention

Tags: file-management, document-management

I'm looking for a tool for record retention, with the following requirements:

- [must] be installable on-site
  To satisfy legal needs, no data leaves the building.
- [must] provide API for upload
  For integration with other products.
- [must] Handle millions of documents without performance loss
  So dropping everything in a Windows folder is out of the question.
- [must] Allow filtering by metadata, including metadata of other types than string, like date/time
- [must] Allow for purging of old documents
- [should] Allow encryption of stored files
- [nice to have] Access audit

*Not* required:

- Capture: scan, OCR, OMR - because documents are electronically generated in the first place
- full text search - searching by metadata is enough
- Validation - not required because it's already done by the system this tool will be integrating with
- Distribution, other than archiving. Only a few user accounts should have access to the documents
- Workflow, versioning, collaboration - documents are generated automatically, and they're read-only
- Federated search - single archive
- Publishing & reproduction - internal use only

I know, Google should be my friend. But by googling I only learned that

- a CMS *may*, if configured, satisfy the requirements, but I assume a CMS is not usually designed with document archiving in mind
- a DMS like LogicalDoc, OpenKM, ContentCentral, or Alfresco should cover most of the needs out of the box, but it may be overkill

So it looks like what I need is a dumbed-down / minimal DMS built specifically for record retention. Is there a name for such a tool? Can you recommend any specific such tool, based on your own experience? Feels like I'm not using the right keyword.

Comment: Would an internal git or other version control system work?

Answer (score 1):

Alfresco and its Records Management extension is the right tool for this. I don't believe it is overkill.

- Installable on-site: Yes, you can download the software and install it on your internal network, no Internet needed
- API for upload: Yes, the CMIS standard allows uloading
- Handle millions of documents without performance loss: Yes, people are storing crazy amounts. See how [this guy](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/204986-capacity-planning-forecasting#comment-733966) has servers with "tens of million of documents".
- Allow filtering by metadata, including metadata of other types than string, like date/time: Yes, backed by built-in Solr.
- Allow for purging of old documents: That's what the Records Management extension does.
- Allow encryption of stored files: Yes, see [the documentation](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/encrypted-overview.html).
- Access audit: Not by default, but you can enable audit and set it up to record READ events. The [audit configuration](http://docs.alfresco.com/5.2/concepts/audit-intro.html) learning curve is a bit steep but there is good documentation.

*Disclaimer: I don't work for Alfresco, but I am member of the open source project, and I sometimes develop solutions based on Alfresco.*

Comment: Your endorsements might indeed be accurate, but you still need to disclose your involvement in the Alfresco project

Comment: @steampowered: Done :-)